# WebView with offline page (HTML5)

Tags: android, html, android-webview, chromium

I'm trying to show an interactive HTML5 page to a user offline using a WebView. Downloaded and unzipped the necessary content and launched the WebView with `web.loadUrl("file:///" + uri.toString());` While most of the stuff works there is no audio and LogCat tells me the following:

```
03-02 17:58:58.082  12066-12205/- D/MediaResourceGetter﹕ canonicalized file path: /data/data/${package.name}/cache/684.unpacked/story_content/video_6kjafYSyahO_30_48_370x208.mp4   
03-02 17:58:58.083  12066-12205/- E/MediaResourceGetter﹕ Refusing to read from unsafe file location.`  
03-02 17:58:58.083  12066-12205/- E/MediaResourceGetter﹕ Unable to configure metadata extractor
```

I choose the cache directory because according to the source of MediaResourceGetter this should be a safe location.
This is how i configured my WebView:

```
WebSettings s = web.getSettings();  
s.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);  
s.setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NARROW_COLUMNS);  
s.setUseWideViewPort(true);  
s.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);  
s.setSavePassword(true);  
s.setSaveFormData(true);  
s.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);  

s.setGeolocationEnabled(true);  
s.setGeolocationDatabasePath("/data/data/" + getPackageName() +  "/geoloc/");  

s.setDomStorageEnabled(true);  

s.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);  
s.setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);  
s.setAllowFileAccess(true);  
s.setAllowContentAccess(true);  
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {  
  s.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);  
  s.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);  
}
```

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?

Comment: @CuriousMind To be honest: I don't know anymore :/ It's been a long time since I had the Problem

Answer (score 1):

Based on [source code](http://src.chromium.org/svn/trunk/src/content/public/android/java/src/org/chromium/content/browser/MediaResourceGetter.java) of `getRawAcceptableDirectories` method, WebView should allow to read files from the app cache directory and the sdcard directory.

Answer (score 0):

Thats work me ...

add your html files to "/main/assets/app/" directory

and write code:

w.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/app/YOUR_HTML_FILE_NAME.html");

Comment: It's a path inside my APK, right? This won't work as i dynamically download the ZIPs and extract them.

Comment: OK, so this is not going to work. At least not for me/for my requirements :/